# How do you use the plunder mine ability?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I gave my secondary hero the Plunder Mine and Destroy Mine abilities.

Then I walked up to a mine. Nothing happened.

Skipped a turn and tried to visit it with full movement. Nothing.

I even tried selecting it from the ability window.

What am I missing?  How do you activate the skill?

Comment: Was the mine owned by one of your enemies?

Comment: Yes, it was owned by an enemy :)

Comment: Did you check in your adventure spells? I think that might be the place where they put abilities like that.

Comment: @murgatroid This is prbly the answer (not at home right now, can't check). For some reason I didn't think of checking the spells for that. If you make it an answer, I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to find the Plunder Mine ability in the spell book and cast it as a spell when you are standing at a mine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have 100 movement points to use this ability.

From [this guide](http://www.heroesvi.com/heroes-vi/might-and-magic-heroes-vi-realm-abilities.html):

> Plunder Mine – The Hero consumes 100 movement points to plunder an
>   enemy mine, immediately taking 3 days worth of productions in advance.
>   The mine stops production for the plundered days. If one of your
>   secondary heroes has some spare time and ability points you might have
>   some fun with this, but, mainly, don’t waste your time. Reputation:
>   Neutral. Active adventure ability. Mana cost: 0. Requires: Hero lvl 5.